# route specific audio to different output

Tags: macos, audio

I have a bluetooth headset that I like to use for calls (Skype / Hangouts from a tab in Chrome) but I also want to have music from the Spotify app playing on my laptop speakers.

On PC I'd got things set up so the audio routed how I wanted (headset was the default communications device, speakers as the general default), but on macOS I can't work out a way to do it - it seems that it's all or nothing to an output device, and I can't select the headset for Skype, WebEx,and Chrome tabs (all of them, or just ones I can identify by, eg, title) and keep Spotify using speakers

Comment: The answer is 'something from Rogue Amoeba' [depending on your needs/wallet] - see a couple of my many answers on Ask Different regarding this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300106/how-to-include-external-microphone-audio-in-headphones/300155#300155 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/203004/nice-audio-mixer-repeater/203009#203009

Comment: thanks! not sure it's enough of a problem to spend $99 on, but might kick the tires (for 10 mins!) on the $10 option

Comment: I've never actually used the new one - SoundSource - but, yes, the others are a bit expensive for what is essentially a one-trick pony. There is simply no better alternative if you need their greater functionality. If you don't, go with the cheap one ;-)